# When adding a text using UITextField from another controller it doesn't show up in the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create a Web app. I use Split View. In my main view I have and Add button, where I enter the name of the page and its URL, after I press save and it should show up in the UITableView as a new row. All the buttons work, but new row doesn't appear. I'm not sure why.

Here is my main UITableView

```
   import UIKit
import WebKit class WebBrowsers: UITableViewController, NewDelegate {
   
   private var list:[List] = [
       List(name: "google", url: URL(string: "https://google.com")),
       List(name: "facebook", url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com"))
   ]
   
   @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
   
   
   @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       let addContactVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AddBrowser") as! AddBrowser
           addContactVC.delegate = self
           navigationController?.pushViewController(addContactVC, animated: true)
           addContactVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   }
   
   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       navigationItem.title = "Browsers"
       // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
       // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

       // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
       // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
       return list.count
   }

   
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
       // Configure the cell...

       return cell
   }
   
   func addSomeCell(name: String?, url:URL!){
       let listNew = List.init(name: name,url: url)
       self.list.append(listNew)
       myTableView.reloadData()
   }

   /*
   // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
       // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
       return true
   }
   */

   /*
   // Override to support editing the table view.
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .delete {
           // Delete the row from the data source
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       } else if editingStyle == .insert {
           // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
       }    
   }
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       
       if segue.identifier == "showDetail"{
           if let navcon = segue.destination as? UINavigationController{
               if let destination = navcon.visibleViewController as? infoBrowser{
               if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row{
                   destination.detailUrl = list[row].url 
                   destination.navigationItem.title = list[row].name
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       
   }

   }
   public protocol NewDelegate: class{
   func addSomeCell(name: String?, url:URL!)}
```

here is my AddButton ViewController

```
import UIKit

class AddBrowser: UIViewController {
  var delegate: NewDelegate?

  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
  
  
  @IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
  

  @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      self.delegate?.addSomeCell(name: nameTextField.text!, url: URL(string: urlTextField.text!))
              navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
      
  }
  /*
  // MARK: - Navigation

  // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
      // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  } }
```

Comment: code seems to be fine. are you sure the delegate gets called back ? Also you dont need the outlet 'myTableView', just call self.tableview, as your controller is a subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: I changed as you said mytableview.reloadData() to self.tableview.reloadData(). but it still doesn't change. Are there any other technical part where I could have made mistake?

Comment: no, removing outlet will not fix your issue. It is an improvement you could make. does your table initally show two rows ? Also you could remove " addContactVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen" while pushing a view controller, it isnt needed

Comment: is there a segue somewhere or your push the navController programmatically as shown ?

Comment: is there is a segue Show which is a pop up view with View only. where I have may buttons and text field. that is why I use addContactVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen. My two main text field work (which are google and Facebook )